# Getting CoreNLP parse tree xml attribute value as tree using R

Tags: xml, r

I am using Stanford CoreNLP to get the parse tree of a sentence. It produces an xml output and I am processing it using the XML package in R. I am able to retrieve the attribute value of the parse node in the xml document using the following command:

**xpathApply(doc, "//parse", xmlValue)[[1](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)]**

I get the attribute value as a string-like thing but What I want is to get the original parse tree with the hierarchies intact in it, as shown below to do some post-processing on it- more specifically, some tree operations on it.

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/

So how do I do it? I could get the attribute value but not in the tree form, how to get the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this anything like the "string-like" value you mention? `(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (NP (NN sausage)))))
    (. .)))`

If so, the hierarchie is intact...

Comment: What kind of R object would you expect? A nested list? If the xml file contains only the string value, there isnothing you can do but parse the string output into a nested list. I understand that this is not trivial, but you can surely find resources to help you.

Comment: On the other hand, if the xml file contains the tree in structured xml, then you can use `xmlTreeParse` to preserve the structure. Some example data would help to help.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like that. As you said, hierarchy is intact here but how to convert that to a tree structure? that's the question.

But I think I've now understood what you said, and am working towards it. Thanks!

Comment: I found relevant pseudo-code on stackoverflow as top links of a relevant google query... Again, if the data in the xml file is structured (and not simply a string), you can extract directly. Otherwise search for "parse bracketed list" or "parenthesis matching", etc.